# Access deletes query after macro exports to excel "Query must have at least one destination field"

Tags: sql, macros, ms-access-2010, export-to-excel

MS Access randomly deletes a SQL query's content when a non-vba macro exports the query contents to excel. The initial export works and the data is exported to Excel correctly, but then (about 50% of the time...) the SQL underlying the query goes missing. This is *definitely* triggered by the export (one can do a before and after comparison of the query).

[The following site](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/access-error-query-destination-field.html) references the problem and talks about a VBA solution that automaticaly rebuilds the SQL query. I'd much prefer to just prevent this from happening rather than fixing it post-mortem. [This forum post on bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/620958-destination-field) also discusses the issue. The suggested solution is not relevant.

The problem database was originally designed in Access 2007 and is now being used in Access 2010. All the queries and macros that are involved in this issue were created using Access 2007. These components were stable in Access 2007. This leads me to believe that the problem is not contained within the SQL. All the SQL queries are simple SELECT statements, there are no inserts, drop or make table commands.

Comment: It's not just if you do it in a macro. This just happened to me when I manually exported a query to Excel (right-click query -> Export -> Excel -> …). Oh and it's not the query you just exported that it zaps, it's the one it depended on. !!?!??!!?!?!!!???? I also have a saved query that simply crashes Access any time you open it. I named it `Z_RunToCrashAccess`. It's a feature. LET ANYONE WHO STUMBLES ON THIS COMMENT BE WARNED: Never use Access for anything, ever. Never ever. Never ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever I'm out of characters. Ever.

Comment: I fixed it by hard coding the query in VBA and then running the VBA macro as soon as the export step of the original macro was done. This replaces the query each time and prevents it from going missing. Real pain in the bottom b/c one must update the VBA code anytime they want to change the query.

Answer (score 2):

I've just encountered this bug myself. None of the solutions posted here worked/were applicable to my case, and I wasn't 100% happy with the work-arounds offered, particularly the geeksengine.com one, which requires that you delete the Query entirely and re-create it from code that you've stored in VBA - not a very generalisable solution, and if someone else has to maintain your database, they'll find themselves perplexed to discover that the Query they changed occasionally reverts itself to its old code, seemingly at random.

So I took a different approach, and wrote a generic routine that stores the SQL code of a Query before exporting the Spreadsheet, and then restores the code immediately afterwards if it's been erased:

```vb
Sub SafeSendQuery(QueryName As String, FileType As Variant, EmailAddresses As String, SubjectLine As String, BodyText As String)

Dim QueryCode As String

'Access has a bug where it sometimes erases the SQL code of the Query it's sending as a spreadsheet
'This stores the code in a string, so that we can restore it if it's been erased
QueryCode = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName).SQL

DoCmd.SendObject ObjectType:=acSendQuery, ObjectName:=QueryName, OutputFormat:=FileType, To:=EmailAddresses, Subject:=SubjectLine, MessageText:=BodyText, EditMessage:=True

'If the SQL code was erased, restore it
If CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName).SQL <> QueryCode Then
    Debug.Print "SQL Code Missing, restoring it now."
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName).SQL = QueryCode
End If

End Sub
```

Note that I wrote this for `DoCmd.SendObject`, as my users need to email the spreadsheet, but it should work just as well for `DoCmd.OutputTo` - just replace the `DoCmd.SendObject` line with a `DoCmd.OutputTo` one, and modify the parameters as necessary.

This is what a subroutine that calls it looks like:

```vb
Sub EmailAQuery()

Dim QueryName As String
Dim FileType As Variant
Dim EmailAddresses As String
Dim SubjectLine As String
Dim BodyText As String

QueryName = "Quarterly Figures"
FileType = acFormatXLSX
EmailAddresses = "bob@company.com; Sally@company.com"
SubjectLine = "Quarterly Figures for " & Format(Date, "mmmm yyyy")
BodyText = "Please see the Quarterly figures data for " & Format(Date, "mmmm yyyy") & ", attached."

Call SafeSendQuery(QueryName, FileType, EmailAddresses, SubjectLine, BodyText)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the expression builder to represent the query in access language?

Double click 'criteria' in the query design window, and build the expression.

For example:

```
SELECT table1.field1 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.field1 LIKE table2.field1
```

This query would become cleared, even though it worked. Use the expression builder to build the "LIKE" expression.  It should look like this:

```
SELECT table1.field1 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.field1 = table2.field1
WHERE ((([table1]![field1] LIKE [table2]![field1])));
```

Comment: Hey! The raw SQL of the query that is being cleared already matches the format that would be created by the expression builder. Not sure that this is the issue but thank you for the suggestion! I'll keep prodding it and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: In your existing SQL `WHERE` statements, replace the period (.) characters with exclamation points (!).  Your SQL Query may look like: `WHERE ((([table1].[field1] LIKE [table2].[field1])));` but it should look like `WHERE ((([table1]![field1] LIKE [table2]![field1])));`.

Comment: Tried it! Didn't do the trick ultimately. It seems like the issue is rooted in the macro itself. This macro exports multiple queries at a time; modifying a copy of the macro to export one query at a time seems to solve the issue. This is not the desired behavior however. I tried recreating the macro from scratch, but it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by modifying the query. Initially the query was joining three tables through both inner and outer joins. I simplified the query into just one join by using an intermediate table, after which Access ceases to delete the query after it runs the macro. This is definitely a bug, one where Access chokes when its macro is tasked to run a query with complex joins.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue in Access 2010.  I was able to resolve it by using an `OpenQuery` action before the `ExportWithFormatting` action and a `CloseWindow – Query` action after the `ExportWithFormatting` action in my macro.  In this way, the query would open, then export, and then close all within the same macro.  I also used a `StopMacro` action at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Access 2010.
For me this was caused by a bug that only occurs if I collected these queries in a group.
Once I removed them from the custom group and left them as unassigned objects, the queries remained intact.